# Ctrl + L Copies Animation Data, but Animation Doesn't Play

Tags: animation, armature, keyframes

Just like the title says. I'm copying animation data from one armature to another with CTRL+L. The animation data copies over, but the armature does nothing. Any idea?

Edit: My file is 275mb with just two armatures. Not even any meshes. I can't upload to pasteall or Blend-Exchange. Any other way to do this?

Comment: You would have to transfer (at least) your vertex groups as well.

Comment: what about testing this functionality with an lightweight armature + mesh with just 2 or 3 bones? Then you can quicker do the test and upload your blend file so we can check it out.

Comment: Do both armatures have the same bones names?

Comment: So I know this worked sometime in the past. I don't know if they have the same bone names, because I just ran a test with some armatures from MakeHuman and Mixamo and the animations transfer over. I'm just gonna Append my textures and particle systems over to new meshes.

Answer (score 0):

After testing with MakeHuman and Mixamo characters, it's working for me now. I got the characters I was using before from the same source, but maybe something happened after turning them into collections and appending.